# string array not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to see my array rendered everytime I select an option from my dropdown. But, it doesn't show immediately on changing elements in dropdown. How can I solve this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const removeTags = (tagToRemove, currentTag, setCurrentTag) => {
  let temp = currentTag;
  setCurrentTag(temp.filter(each => each !== currentTag));
};

export default function App() {
  const [currentTag, setCurrentTag] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={e => {
          let temp = currentTag;
          temp.push(e.target.value);
          console.log(temp);
          setCurrentTag(temp);
        }}
      >
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      {currentTag !== null
        ? currentTag.map((each, index) => (
            <span
              key={index}
              className="tag"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            >
              <span className="tag is-link" style={{ marginLeft: ".5em" }}>
                {each}
              </span>
              <a
                className="tag is-delete"
                onClick={() => removeTags(each, currentTag, setCurrentTag)}
              />
            </span>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my code, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-array-example-dhbrx)

Comment: Because you did not included code instead included code link. And your post quality is low (title doesn't describes your problem, content is not helpful). PS: i'm not the down voter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The function to update state value setCurrentTag accepts a new state value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

```
  <select
    onChange={e => {
      setCurrentTag([...currentTag, e.target.value]);
    }}
  >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
```

Your mistake was to mutate state value and pass it to setCurrentTag instead of creating a new value

```
  onChange={e => {
    let temp = currentTag; // currentTag is an array, so temp store reference to that array, and not a new array

    temp.push(e.target.value); // push method changes array temp, which refers to currentTag

    console.log(temp);
    setCurrentTag(temp); // pass the same mutated currentTag array
 }}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-react-array-example-tdts8

Comment: Also please explain what changes you have made from OP's code which is helpful for all to understand better rather than just posting the code and sandbox link..

Answer (score 1):

To add items to array state you can use `setState` like that:

```js
setCurrentTag(old => [...old, newItem]);
```

And to remove item from the array use like this:

```js
setCurrentTag(old => old.filter(a => a != itemToRemove));
```

Here's [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-array-example-btqg2).

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [currentTag, setCurrentTag] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={e => {
          let value = e.target.value;
          setCurrentTag(old => [...old, value]);
        }}
      >
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      {currentTag !== null
        ? currentTag.map((each, index) => (
            <span
              key={index}
              className="tag"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            >
              <span className="tag is-link" style={{ marginLeft: ".5em" }}>
                {each}
              </span>
              <a
                className="tag is-delete"
                onClick={() => {
                  setCurrentTag(old => old.filter(a => each !== a));
                }}
              />
            </span>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { isEmpty } from "lodash";

function addTags(e, value, setCurrentTag, setAllSectorsSelected) {
  console.log("in addTags,e,value: ", e, value);
}

const removeTags = (tagToRemove, currentTag, setCurrentTag) => {
  let temp = currentTag;
  setCurrentTag(temp.filter(each => each !== currentTag));
};

export default function App() {
  const [currentTag, setCurrentTag] = useState([]);

  const tagSelector = event => {
    // spreading over the previously added options
    setCurrentTag([...currentTag, event.target.value]);
  };

  console.log({ currentTag });
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={event => tagSelector(event)}>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      <DisplayOption {...{ currentTag, setCurrentTag }} />
    </div>
  );
}

function DisplayOption(props) {
  const { currentTag, setCurrentTag } = props;

  if (isEmpty(currentTag)) return null;

  return currentTag.map((each, index) => (
    <span key={index} className="tag" style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <span
        className="tag is-link"
        style={{ marginLeft: ".5em", fontSize: "16px", fontColor: "red" }}
      >
        {each}
      </span>
      <div
        href=""
        className="tag is-delete"
        onClick={() => removeTags(each, currentTag, setCurrentTag)}
      />
    </span>
  ));
}
```